# How does the maximum principle apply to show that $v = 0$ in $U$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maximum-principle, elliptic-equations

My question concerns one part of the proof of Theorem 3 in §6.5 in PDE Evans.

> We consider in this section the boundary-value problem
> $$\begin{cases}Lw=\lambda w & \text{in }U \\ \, \, \, \, w=0 & \text{on }\partial U \end{cases} \tag{1}$$ where $U$ is open, bounded, and recall that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L$ provided there exists a nontrival solution of $(1)$.

The main theorem:

> **THEOREM 3** (Principal eigenvalue for nonsymmetric elliptic operators)**.**
>
> (i) *There exists a real eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ for the operator $L$, taken with zero boundary conditions, such that if $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ is any other eigenvalue, we have $$\operatorname{Re}(\lambda) \ge \lambda_1.$$*
>
> (ii) *There exists a corresponding eigenfunction $w_1$, which is positive within $U$.*
>
> (iii) *The eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is simple; that is, if $u$ is any solution of $(1)$, then $u$ is a multiple of $w_1$.*

The full proof of Theorem 3 is too long, so I'm linking **[a PDF file of it](http://www.docdroid.net/zVMNYDk/proof-of-theorem-3-in-65.pdf.html)**. However, I will print part of the proof below, the part which I have a question about. This is towards the end of the paragraph of step 6 in the proof.

> Consequently $$K(|v|^2) \le 2(\operatorname{Re} \lambda - (1-\epsilon)\lambda_1)|v|^2 \quad \text{in }U.$$ Thus if $\operatorname{Re} \lambda \le (1-\epsilon)\lambda_1$, then $K(|v|^2) \le 0$ in $U$. As $v=0$ on $\partial U$, according to $(33)$ and $(39)$, we deduce from the maximum principle that $v=\frac uw = 0$ in $U$. Thus, $u \equiv 0$ in $U$ and so $\lambda$ cannot be an eigenvalue. This conclusion obtains for each $\epsilon > 0$, and so $\operatorname{Re} \lambda \ge \lambda_1$ if $\lambda$ is any complex eigenvalue.

**My question:**

Given that $K(|v|) \le 0$ in $U$ and $v = 0$ on $\partial U$, how does the maximum principle apply here to show that $v = 0$ in $U$? This is needed to show that $u \equiv 0$ in $U$ (since $w$ is not identically zero and arbitrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Evans means the (weak) maximum principle for elliptic PDE's. Elliptic PDE generalizes Laplacian. Let's see how it is for the simplest case. If we have 
$-\Delta u\le 0$ in $U$ then the function $u$ is subharmonic, so it satisfies the Mean Value theorem with inequality
$$
u(a)\le \frac{1}{|\partial B(a)|}\int_{\partial B(a)}u(\xi)\,dS_\xi,
$$
with the straightforward conclusion that $\max_{\bar U} u=\max_{\partial U} u$.

For elliptic PDE there is a similar result: if $u\in C^2(U)\cap C(\bar U)$ and 
$$
Ku=-\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}u_{x_i,x_j}+\sum_{i}b_iu_{x_i}\le 0
$$
then $\max_{\bar U} u=\max_{\partial U} u$. /Check it, for example, [here, page 67](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~miersemann/pde2book.pdf)./

The argument in the paper goes: since $K(|v|^2)\le 0$ and $v|_{\partial U}=0$, we have that $|v|^2\le 0$ in $U$, which gives obviously $v\equiv 0$ in $U$. Perhaps, this kind of maximum principle is mentioned somewhere earlier in the Chapter.

Comment: I read page 67 of the paper you linked. Since $K(|v|^2) \le 0$, this means $|v|^2$ is subharmonic and so, according to the paper, the *infimum* is obtained: $$\inf_{x \in \overline{U}} |v|^2 = \inf_{x \in \partial U} |v|^2 = 0.$$ This means $|v|^2 \ge 0$ in $U$. So how do we still obtain $|v|^2 \le 0$ in $U$?

Comment: @Cookie On the page 67 they have the *opposite* sign to Evans. If you look at the beginning of the page you''ll see that they define $Mu=-Ku$.

Comment: The beginning of page 67 in the paper defines $$Mu = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} u_{x_i x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^{'} u_{x_i},$$ whereas Evans defines $$Ku = -\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} u_{x_i x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^{'} u_{x_i}.$$ How is $Mu=-Ku$? Only the first term of $Ku$ has the negative sign.

Comment: Exactly! The opposite sign in front of the quadratic form (second derivatives) makes the difference. It becomes supremum, not infimum. Linear terms are not important. You can call $b'=-b$ if you wish.

Comment: So, first of all, only the second-order term determines whether the operator is elliptic or not (I know, that sounds obvious now that I'm typing this). And, speaking in terms of only Evans' notation at this time, we see that $K(|v|^2) \le 0$ is considered to be subharmonic. As a consequence, the *supremum* is attained on the boundary $\partial U$. This means $|v|^2 \le 0$ in $U$ like you said in your answer. Since (obviously) $|v| \ge 0$, we deduce that $v \equiv 0$. (Is my understanding correct?)

Comment: @Cookie That's right. The only thing is that the name *subharmonic* is reserved for the Laplacian. For $Ku\le 0$ it is no longer called subharmonic (as well as $Ku=0$ is not called harmonic). P.S. I found one more link for you [here](https://fishingalone.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/maximum-principle-for-elliptic-differential-equation/) (with the correct sign for $b_i$ :-))